# Apache ignores WSGIScriptAlias if same directory exists in root

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, python, django, mod-wsgi

I notice a peculiar error when serving Django app through mod_wsgi.

In my document root, I have `/admin` directory that is restricted to 127.0.0.1 using `LocationMatch` directive. I also have `/admin` URLConf mounted on / in Django app, which is standard path for Django's autogenerated admin interface. The app itself is under `/app` path, configured with `WSGIScriptAlias` directive.

Now, Apache somehow treats each request for `/app/admin` and it's subpaths as directed to both app and document root. I get Django's admin displayed, but error.log contains line like this one:
`[Tue Feb 14 01:25:35.538501 2017] [authz_core:error] [pid 29235] [client 32.135.203.150:36412] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/admin/`

This is almost non-issue, apart from two things:

- I had to turn off fail2ban,
- I can't upload files in admin, and I suspect this is the reason why, because this error appear each time i try (receiving 500 as response).

This is solved by either renaming my html directory or Django's admin app, but I would really like to find the right solution that lets me have both.

Apache configuration in Debian is split in multiple files, but I believe the relevant parts are as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    Include conf-available/default.conf

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <LocationMatch ^/admin>
        Require ip 127.0.0.1 ::1
    </LocationMatch>

    <LocationMatch ^/admin/status>
        SetHandler server-status
    </LocationMatch>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    SetEnvIf Request_URI "/admin/status" nolog
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined env=!nolog
</VirtualHost>
```

default.conf:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        DirectoryIndex disabled
        AllowOverride Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /app/static/ /var/www/app/static/
    Alias /app/media/ /var/www/app/media/

    <Directory /var/www/app/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/app/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess pbf.net.pl python-path=/var/www/app:/usr/local/virtualenvs/app/lib/python3.4/site-packages/
    WSGIProcessGroup app
    WSGIScriptAlias /app /var/www/app/wsgi.py process-group=app
    # WSGIPythonPath /var/www/app/
    <Directory /var/www/app>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
```